# My CSS tooltip only text, not Images

Tags: html, css

I wrote some CSS for a tool tip

```
.toolTip{
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
}

.toolTip:hover:after{
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(title);
    left: 20%;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
    width: 220px;
}
```

HTML

```
    <p title="tester" class="toolTip">test</p>
    <img src="images/people/Tapolci_Jeff_abg_web.png" class="toolTip" title="Jeff T." alt="Jeff Tapolci" />
```

It only works with the text, but not the image. How can I fix this?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/se47L/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to note that `img` elements are **[replaced elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element)** so psuedo elements such as `:before` or `:after` will not work unfortunately. You should wrap it in, say, a `span` and add the class to that.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/se47L/1/)

---

**Replaced Elements:**

> In CSS, a replaced element is an element whose representation is
>   outside the scope of CSS. These are kind of external objects whose
>   representation is independant of the CSS. Typical replaced elements
>   are `<img>`, `<object>`, `<video>` or forms element like `<textarea>`,
>   `<input>`. Some elements, like  or  are replaced elements
>   only in specific cases. Object inserted using the CSS content
>   properties are anonymous replaced elements.